# How to compare values in different collections that need different type of iteration loops?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Lets say you have an Iterator which will contains values that you need to compare with values that are located in a separate List.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = aObj.items();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Object> item = it.next();
    nameValue = item.getNameValue();
    keyValue = item.getKeyValue();
    System.out.println("Name: " + nameValue);
    System.out.println("Value: " + keyValue);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Name: header
Value: 22222
```

Lets say you have a separate list (in which you want to compare the above values with):

```
List<Items> items = new ArrayList<>();

for (Item item : items) {
    itemNameValue = item.getName();
    itemKeyValue = item.getKey();
    System.out.println("Name: " + itemNameValue);
    System.out.println("Value: " + itemKeyValue);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Name: header
Value: 44444
```

Since these are different types of loops (one is a while loop and the other one is a for each loop) 
how can you compare for example:

```
if (nameValue.equals(itemNameValue())) {
    // do something?
}
```

I need to iterate over both collections / data structures at the same time...

Would this be the solution?

```
String nameValue = "";
Object keyValue = "";
String itemNameValue = "";
String itemKeyValue = "";

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = aObj.items();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Object> item = it.next();
    nameValue = item.getNameValue();
    keyValue = item.getKeyValue();
    for (Item item : items) {
        itemNameValue = item.getName();
        itemKeyValue = item.getKey();
    }
    if (nameValue.equals(itemNameValue())) {
        // do something?
    }
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to ask (in a very simplified way is this):

(1) The collection that needs to be iterated in a while loop is just test input (sample data)

(2) The array list from the second collection is really a list of data which was returned from a database call (DAO) and placed into the ArrayList.

I am trying to verify if the input from Iterator inside the while loop is the same as the values from the ArrayList (which came from a database). Since these are different data structures requiring different looping mechanisms. How could I iterate through both data structures at the same time and compare them? The second data structure (the array list) is the actual set of values that are correct.

I don't know if there's a guarantee that each iteration would be comparing the same items if I use a nested loop?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - you said you wanted to loop over both collections at the same time but you are written a nested loop. Further, your nested loop makes no sense. Please describe exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Boris... I am trying to compare values belonging to two different data structures. These data structures use different ways to iterate through them. The Iterator one is a sample data. The second ArrayList is the actual data which the sample data must equal. Do you understand what I am trying to solve?

Comment: No, I do not. 1) provide sample data. 2) provide expected output. 3) explain fully what the processing is. But most importantly, update your question with the pertinent information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is a direct result of a BAD Application design.
The underline **incorrect** assumption of this question is that the map and the list will hold the objects in the same sequence.

- List --> A data structure that is ordered by not sorted
- Map --> A data structure that is neither ordered nor sorted

This is not to say that these two data structures don't work well together. However, using them to store the same list should only result from an awkward program design.

Even though to answer your question, you can use the below code to accomplish this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = aObj.items();
List<Items> items = dbCall.getItems(); // Get the list of Items from the DB
int index = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Object> itemFromMap = it.next();
    Item itemFromList = items.get(index);
    if(itemFromMap.getNameValue().equals(itemFromList.getName()) && 
            itemFromMap.getKeyValue().equals(itemFromList.getKey())){
        // If you prefer a single .equals() method over &&, then you can implement a Comparator<Item>
        return false;
    }
    index++;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Herin... Thank you very much. It was my fault that its a bad application design. I did create a DB call via a DAO which brought back a list of items, but the Map is really the only way to get Jackson Json key / value pairs using Jackson API. See my other post http://tinyurl.com/parseJacksonJson? Given this, how would you design this to be a better design?

Comment: I have answered this question on the corresponding page. You need to use JSON libraries such as GSON or JACKSON to parse JSON strings to objects or list of objects (which in your case will be Items)